# Understanding of development cycle of C++ program

Tags: c++

I am very new to the programming world. I have started with the book *Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days* by Jesse Liberty. I have few basic and some silly doubts.

On page 15, the author explains the process of creating a program--the development cycle. In that section, many terms are there, corresponding to them I have some doubts which I am listing below. I have run my first C++ program helloworld (by following instructions from one youtube video). I am first writing entire process mentioning what I have done to run my first ever program.

I am using windows 10 and gcc compiler. So, first I wrote my code in notepad as below as mentioned in book.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Then:

1. I saved it as `helloworld.cpp`.
2. I opened command prompt and typed `g++`.
3. I changed directory to where I saved my file.
4. I ran `g++ helloworld.cpp`. Now in same folder, where I saved my file, one file named `a.exe` got created.
5. I ran `a.exe` and the screen showed `Hello world!`. Now coming back to the doubts that I have related to those technical terms.

In my above mentioned process

1. What does "invoking a compiler" mean? When did that occur, step 1?
2. When did my source file get compiled? (Is it after step 4?)

Now author says, after your source file is compiled, an object file is produced (with extension `.obj` or `.o`). To turn this into an executable program, "you must run a linker " (i.e. you have to link your object file with needed libraries).

3. Where do I find that object file after compilation process?
4. What is the process "you must run a linker"? When did that happen in my above mentioned process?
5. Where is the executable program? (Is it `a.exe`?)

Comment: @ArdentCoder In that case I recommend you stop using an IDE for a while and learn these details, because they actually *matter* for C++. After that feel free to go back to using an IDE, of course.

Comment: I don't see a reason why my original comment was deleted, *"I think you don't use an IDE. These questions never came to my mind because of that :P"*. @KonradRudolph Yah, sure thing :)

Comment: @ArdentCoder Shame, it was a valid comment … IDEs hide many of these details and most of the time that’s great. Anyway, I haven’t taught C++ intro in a few years so I’m not entirely up to date on the best learning resources but I’ve had a quick look and [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) looks like a good intro for manual compilation of C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you very much! Let me add something more to this comment or it will get deleted as well lol. I don't care if the link is outdated, I just needed a starting point ;) Edit: haha that link has the answers to many of these questions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph lots of thanks for that link

Comment: @KonradRudolph can I know how to rename the link we want to share like you did above using word "this"?

Comment: @Believer See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What does "invoking a compiler" mean? When did that occur, step 1?

"Invoking" just means running a program. Your compiler is `g++`, which is the C++ front-end for the GNU Compiler Collection.

You ran it once in step 2, presumably just to check it was installed, and then ...

> 2. When did my source file get compiled?

When you ran `g++` again in step 4, where you gave it the name of your source code file, and it compiled (and linked) that into `a.exe`.

> 3. Where do I find that object file after compilation process?

Probably in the same directory from which you ran the compiler, and in which you found the linked executable.

I don't recall whether `g++` keeps the intermediate object file around in this case, on this platform - if it isn't there, you can generate it manually with

```
g++ -c helloworld.cpp
```

The `-c` option means "compile but do not link". You can see it described in the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options). This will save the intermediate object file.

> 4. What is the process "you must run a linker"? When did that happen in my above mentioned process?

GCC does this for you, by default (ie, *unless* you add the `-c` option).

> 5. Where is the executable program? (Is it a.exe?)

Yep, that's it. An "executable" is just a file you can execute (ie, running or "invoking" it). That's what the `.exe` suffix is short for.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `g++`, which does linking for you, so you're getting the executable (a.exe). I think you should add `-c` to command line if you want object file (a.obj), and then you can link it with `ld` (more switches may be needed).

When you run g++ you are invoking pre-processor, compiler, assembler and linker in one go. It can allow you to skip some phases to get intermediate results with command-line switches.